# VSIX Develop: ServiceProvider.GetService return null

Tags: visual-studio, vsix

I build a C# Extensibility -VSIX Project in vs2015. Then I add a new item - VSPackage Custom Command and it works well till I add a TreamFoundation Control Server like this:

`//get null
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.ITeamExplorer teamExplorer;
teamExplorer = this.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.ITeamExplorer)) 
                                      as Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.ITeamExplorer;`

the `teamExplore` get a `null` return, while another `GetService` works well.

`//get return
 OleMenuCommandService commandService = this.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(IMenuCommandService)) as OleMenuCommandService;`

The [MSND](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb138962.aspx) told that `null if the service could not be located.`

but I can not figure out why is happened and how to fix it. Any suggestion? Thank any way:)